# Can I request to change my user ID?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I have noticed that user IDs [6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6) and [7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7) are not in use! Where can I request to change my user ID to one of these?

Comment: Heh, clever! Ohh man, this could be a trophy for deserving users! Like for mods, or high-rep users. Like for example, sympathetic high-rep users from southern Germany.

Comment: Can I get id `-1` in that case?

Comment: If you're going to post links, you could at least get the second one right.

Comment: @Oded I think [Community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) might have something to say about that

Comment: @Oded - dibs on -2

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - I would hope that Oded knows that by now.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Fair point. If Community won't give it up, I'd like to get `0` (then you will have to realise the truth - there is no id).

Comment: Would you also like a [Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta) badge with that?

Comment: Could I then have some of [this guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/) rep? He seems to have too much anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't currently done and there are no plans to add this as a feature.

You'll have to just enjoy the userid you got when you signed up. There is [a 6 *and* a 7 in it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69537/meysam)! :)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that there's already a 6 and 7 in my own ID! Seems like I don't need those individual IDs anymore! thank you Anna! ;)

Comment: @Meysam Any time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I immediately demand that my user ID be switched with [Brad Gilbert's.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert)

Comment: You are too leet, the request has already been declined.